# Examples of bad statistics in Computer Science

Tags: reference-request, education, statistics

I am preparing class materials for the applied statistics class for Ph.D. students and want to present them with examples of bad statistics in different fields of computer science. I am especially interested in the examples form the sub-fields represented in our department:

- CHI
- MIS (with focus on qualitative methods and social experiment design)
- Parallel computing and Big Data
- Databases
- Software engineering (software evolution, software architecture)
- Game theory
- Networks

Maybe you can recommend good literature regarding this topic?

Comment: "Gane theory", I presume you mean "game theory". What kind of 'examples' do you want? Flawed published papers? Papers on education of statistics? Note that your questions seems to encourage a list as answer, which is in general disliked. Can you be a bit more specific about what you want? Perhaps pick one of the subfields and ask whether there are examples within that subfield. That question would be more focussed.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/90117/755, https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107412/705, https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/4576/1106, https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/13896/862. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.